# How to close master view controller in splitViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an app with a split view controller implemented. I also have a setting that overrides the trait collection so all devices are set to regular size classes (instead of compact for iPhones).

I also have a setting in the app that allows users to toggle "split view". This just switches the return value for `targetDisplayModeForActionInSplitViewController` from `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible` to `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeOverlay`.

Most of my view controllers are loaded through segues in the storyboard, however some are loaded programmatically (ex. [self presentViewController...]).

The problem I am having is that when the display mode is set to Overlay, when any of the views are loaded programmatically, the master view controller does not collapse. I have tried dismissing it with code from similar questions, but to no luck. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out for anybody else with the same problem. Manually setting the preferred display mode to hidden will automatically hide the view controller. In my split view controller class I simply added

```
-(void)setDisplayModeHidden {
    self.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden;
}
```

And registered it as an observer in NSNotificationCenter. Whenever I need to close the view controller I just call the function and it will hide it!